# Custom debug engine for Visual Studio in managed code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

We are developing a custom textual DSL, that will ultimately get integrated into Visual Studio IDE.

We would be needing debugger support for the DSL. I could not find any references or samples that show custom debug engines written in managed code (C#). Of course there are a lot of samples where the DE is written as a COM component.

Please note that our custom DSL does not generate any pdb files or emit IL. So using IDE debugger is ruled out.

Could anyone please point me to a managed custom debug engine sample?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following sample than is available on code.msdn.com.  This contains a mostly managed custom debugger sample plus many walk through documents that should get you going.

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/debugenginesample/